# MySQL keep crashing over and over on reading ibd files

Tags: mysql, innodb

My MySQL instance keeps crashing over and over again, I am running it with innodb_force_recovery = 3 innodb_purge_threads=0 I have tried it with force_recovery = 1 as well. It has happened before but it worked after a while but this time it is taking so much time and crashing. Following is the error log, help would be appreciated. I am stuck here.

```
2015-10-02 20:57:28 26379 [Warning] option 'innodb-purge-threads': unsigned value 0 adjusted to 1
2015-10-02 20:57:28 26379 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-10-02 20:57:28 26379 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-10-02 20:57:28 26379 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-10-02 20:57:28 26379 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-10-02 20:57:28 26379 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-10-02 20:57:28 26379 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-10-02 20:57:28 26379 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2015-10-02 20:57:28 26379 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-10-02 20:57:28 26379 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 112.0G
2015-10-02 20:59:07 26379 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-10-02 20:59:33 26379 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-10-02 20:59:33 26379 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 64368316874
2015-10-02 20:59:33 26379 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-10-02 20:59:33 26379 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-10-02 20:59:33 26379 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-10-02 21:09:30 26379 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages

2015-10-02 21:09:30 26379 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 64373559296
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 64378802176
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 64384045056
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 64389287936
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 64394530816
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 64399773696
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 64405016576
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 64410259456
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 64415502336
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 64420745216
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 64425988096
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 64431230976
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 64436473856
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 64441716736
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 64446959616
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 64452202496
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 64457445376
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 64462688256
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 64464934694
2015-10-02 21:09:40 7f2760110720  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 139807092180768 in file trx0undo.cc line 784
InnoDB: Failing assertion: mach_read_from_2(undo_page + TRX_UNDO_PAGE_HDR + TRX_UNDO_PAGE_TYPE) == TRX_UNDO_INSERT
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
01:09:40 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=33554432
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=10000
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 4000736 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.
Thread pointer: 0x0
    Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
    where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
    terribly wrong...
    stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x40000
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x35)[0x8e1555]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x494)[0x6678e4]
    /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf790)[0x7f275fcf5790]
    /lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35)[0x7f275e795625]
    /lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x175)[0x7f275e796e05]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld[0xa23e52]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld[0xa246b4]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x98941e]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x98b4a4]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld[0xa571cf]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld[0xa6cdd4]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld[0xa6d21b]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld[0xa5a864]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld[0xa263fb]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld[0xa1b185]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld[0xa1b506]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld[0xa1d9ae]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld[0xa07667]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x94d6ed]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24ha_initialize_handlertonP13st_plugin_int+0x48)[0x5ab2d8]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x6f10b1]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11plugin_initPiPPci+0xbb6)[0x6f4dd6]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x59dca8]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0x425)[0x5a2d25]
    /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x7f275e781d5d]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x594bfd]
    The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
    information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
    151002 21:09:41 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld-1001.pid ended
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like corrupted UNDO segment. You should start MySQL with `innodb_force_recovery=4`, dump all tables and re-create the database from scratch